# Why won't IntelliJ IDEA create a JAR artifact without a class with Main() method?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Based on the answer to this question:

[How to organize a large java project in Intellij Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26813725/how-to-organize-a-large-java-project-in-intellij-idea)

I am attempting to make a Jar file out of a middle-ware Java component I've authoried with IDEA.  I intend to import this Jar in several related projects all of which leverage the middleware component.

In order to mak ea jar file, I'm instructed to create an "Artifact" using the project structure dialog.  When I do so, the dialog box asks to identify the class with the "Main" method.

But my jar is meant to basically be a library class, and none of the classes have (or need) a main method.  Of course I could create a dummy main method, but the requirement troubles me. Why would I need a class with a main method if I am creating a Jar meant to contain middle ware objects/

[image]

Comment: I use IDEA13 and you are not required to specify a main class. What version are you using?

Comment: What happens when you leave it blank?  Not every box is required to have a value in it.

Comment: Mr. Buck, you turned out to be right.  I see a box, I feel like I have to fill it in.  But in tihs case not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if you have an option set somewhere that the `jar` file in question should be a `runnable jar` file.  Runnable jar files must have a class with a valid `public static void main(String[] args)` method.  That method must be properly documented in the JAR manifest for runnable jar files.

I imagine that since you have (somewhere) a "runnable jar file" selection on, the project won't let you progress until you specify the required "main class"; however, if you reconfigure your project to not need the "runnable" part, then you can still use the jar normally, without specifying the "main class".  The only drawback is that you won't be able to `java -jar <jarfile>` it.